# Control GitHub Requesting Permissions

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can we control the requesting permissions for the [GitHub IDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-github-app) in B2C?

---

I've configured my B2C tenant to allow sign-in's from GitHub but I'm concerned about the requesting permissions of **Full Access**❗

> This application will be able to read and **write all user data**.

Sample app: https://angular-6-b2c.azurewebsites.net/

[image: github permissions request screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we **can't** control this

I did find this info on GitHub docs: [Understanding scopes for OAuth Apps](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/#understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps)

[image: user scope screenshot]

If I manually change the `scope` to `user:email` in the sign-in request URL, I get:

[image: email only request screenshot]
Source: [Request Link](https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=a45a2defacd4719b3ee2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fte%2Fspottedmahnb2c.onmicrosoft.com%2Foauth2%2Fauthresp&response_type=code&scope=user:email&state=StateProperties%3DeyJTSUQiOiJ4LW1zLWNwaW0tcmM6ODM2N2FhOGYtZmY3MS00MDQyLTg0NjctOGUyNzZlNzQxN2M1IiwiVElEIjoiZDBjZWYyOTgtYmYzZC00ZWRhLTk3NGQtOWI3OWQ1ZTI5NjVhIn0)

---

There are no options to control this parameter:

[image: github idp options]

---

UserVoice item: [Reduce GitHub Account Permissions | No Write Access](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/34279063-reduce-github-account-permissions-no-write-acces)